# jboss unable to handle more than 3000 request

Tags: java, performance, web-services, jmeter, jboss5.x

I created a web service both client and server. I thought of doing the performance testing. I tried jmeter with a sample test plan to execute it. Upto 3000 request jboss processed the request but when requests more than 3000 some of the request are not processed (In sense of Can't open connection : Connection refused). Where i have to make the changes to handle more than 10000 request at the same time.  Either it's a jboss issue or System Throughput ?

jmeter Config : 300 Threads, 1 sec ramp up and 10 loop ups.

System (Server Config) : Windows 7, 4G RAM

Comment: So you have only 300 concurrent requests, right (300 threads doing 10 consecutive requests)? So where do you see the 'connection refused', in the client or on the server?

Comment: In the jemeter response . It get it from the server.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Where i have to make the changes to handle more than 10000 request at the same time

**10 thousand** concurrent requests in Tomcat (I believe it is used in JBoss) is quite a lot. In typical setup (with blocking IO connector) you need one thread per one HTTP connection. This is way too much for ordinary JVM. On a 64-bit server machine one thread needs 1 MiB (check out `-Xss` parameter). And you only have 4 GiB.

Moreover, the [number of context switches](http://blog.tsunanet.net/2010/11/how-long-does-it-take-to-make-context.html) will kill your performance. You would need hundreds of cores to effectively handle all these connections. And if your request is I/O or database bound - you'll see a bottleneck elsewhere.

That being said you need a different approach. Either try out non-blocking I/O or asynchronous servlets (since 3.0) or... scale out. By default Tomcat can handle 100-200 concurrent connections (reasonable default) and a similar amount of connections are queued. Everything above that is rejected and you are probably experiencing that.

## See also

- [Advanced IO and Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/aio.html)
- [Asynchronous Support in Servlet 3.0](https://blogs.oracle.com/enterprisetechtips/entry/asynchronous_support_in_servlet_3)

Comment: Your reply sounds good!! So how i can implement a non-blocking I/O (Are you speaking about the non blocking I/O queue or something else)?

Comment: @Mayilarun: I added few links to my answer. In principle with asynchronous servlet 3.0 support you can handle multiple connections with very few threads.

Answer (score 6):

There are two common problems that I think of.

First, if you run JBoss on Linux as a normal user, you can run into 'Too many open files', if you did not edit the limits.conf file. See https://community.jboss.org/thread/155699. Each open socket counts as an 'open file' for Linux, so the OS could block your connections because of this.

Second, the maximum threadpool size for incoming connections is 200 by default. This limits the number of **concurrent requests**, i.e. requests that are in progress at the same time. If you have jmeter doing 300 threads, the jboss connector threadpool should be larger. You can find this in jboss6 in the jboss-web.sar/server.xml. Look for 'maxThreads' in the  element: http://docs.jboss.org/jbossweb/latest/config/http.html.

200 is the recommended maximum for a single core CPU. Above that, the context switches start to give too much overhead, like Tomasz says. So for production use, only increase to 400 on a dual core, 800 on a quad core, etc.